# Find key with max value from SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, max, sorteddictionary

I have a `SortedDictionary` how do I find the key associated with the max value?  Do I have to loop through every KeyValuePair?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you want the maximal key? The `SortedDictionary` is ordered by size of the keys. So that would be the "last" key in a way. It's interesting if there's no fast way to get that! Or are you in fact referring to the maximal value? That's something you'd have to iterate the entire collection for (probably using the `Max` method from Linq.

Comment: Note that the value is not necessarily unique. Do you need all keys holding the MaxValue or will anyone do?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I do not want the maximal key.  I want the key for the maximal value.

Comment: It'd also be helpful to know what types your `TKey` and `TValue` are in the `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: @MareInfinitus anyone will do.  Actually ideally I'd be interested in solutions both ways.

Comment: @User I provided a way to get all MaxValue keys. You can simplify it to get anyone value, but you have the chance to get all of them, too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `dict` is your `SortedDictionary<,>` (or any `IDictionary<,>`) and you want *all* the keys that correspond to the max value, first check that `dict` is not null or empty (you need at least one element). Then maybe this works:

```
var max = dict.Values.Max();
var relevantKeys = dict.Where(pair => max.Equals(pair.Value))
    .Select(pair => pair.Key);
```

Maybe it can be done more efficiently?

Comment: I would write pair.Value.Equals(max), but yes, it looks elegant. I just like fluent code ;)

Comment: @MareInfinitus I thought: It's more probable that some values are `null`, than it is that the `max` is `null` (although that could happen, I guess, if _all_ values are `null`).

Comment: Maybe I should say `Equals(pair.Value, max)`, i.e. the static `Equals`.

Comment: You are right, did not think of `null` values... multiple, but not null ;)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen why did you use the `Equal` method rather than just a plain equal comparison operator (==)?  Wouldn't that skip the null value issue?

Comment: It's because I don't know what type the values are, i.e. I don't know what `TValue` is in your `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. For some types, using `Equals` gives a better result than using `==`. Some reference types re-define `Equals` but do not re-define `==`. And if `TValue` is a struct that you've written yourself, then maybe `==` is not allowed at all! See also Sumo's comment on your question (not on this answer).

Comment: @user407493 As an example, if the dictionary (sorted) holds `{ {"a",25}, {"b",27}, {"c",24}, {"d",27}, {"e",27}, {"f",25}, }`, the answer would be `{"b", "d", "e",}`. The answer can be seen as a sorted set.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this approach can work with a normal `Dictionary`? Meaning that we're not benefiting from the fact that the `SortedDictionary` is well sorted (or so the name suggests).

Comment: @Spidey Sorted dictionaries are sorted by keys, not by value. Just like in my example in the comment just above yours.

Comment: Of course, just wanted to verify that if we don't care about max-min or range of keys then we may as well be using a `Dictionary`. -- and yes I know it was because of the OP

Comment: @Spidey Added "or any `IDictionary<,>`".

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Getting the max key from a SortedDictionary should be an O(1) operation (same with min key).

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld The "funny" thing here is that the asker wants the largest **value** of type `TValue`, and its related key(s). It could be different if they had asked for the largest **key**. Also read previous comments to my answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen In haste, I read the title which is ambiguously stated. The disambiguator is the word "associated with" which is in the body.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Enumerable.OrderByDescending()` and then access the `Key` property of what `First()` returns like so:

```
 var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
                       {
                           {"key1", "value3"},
                           {"key2", "value1"},
                           {"key3", "value2"},
                       };

        var max = dict.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value).First();
        var key = max.Key;
```

Comment: So Max() returns a KeyValuePair not just the max value?

Comment: Didn't down vote you (although I don't see how your answer is different from Martin Devillers). Looks like someone came through and downvoted most of the answers.

Comment: @User No, ours aren't different, but were basically answered at the same time.  I don't know if any of these answers given so far are right/wrong as they all accomplish what you "might" need in similar ways.  It really depends on what your constraints are with `TValue` (if there can be duplicates, nulls, etc).  LINQ gives you a great deal of options whether it's a `SortedDictionary` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the key associated with the max value, means you are not actually using the default ordering of the SortedDictionary. This is because the SortedDictionar orders by Key, rather than Value. So to do what you want, you'd do it the old fashioned LINQ way:

```
sortedDict.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value).First().Key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?spec=svn2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c&r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) to efficiently run this query.

```
var result =  dictionary.MaxBy(pair => pair.Value).Key;
```

This will only need to iterate the data once, as opposed to sorting the values and taking the first result (which will be `O(n * log(n))`).

Since only the keys, rather then the values, are sorted, there is no way of performing this query without at least looping through every keypair once.

Another option would be to have two SortedDictionaries.  One would be the one that you already have, and the other would be a reverse dictionary.  For each value in your current dictionary you could add it as a key to the second dictionary, and the value of the second dictionary would be the key in the first (if it's a one to many relationship rather than a one to one the value of the reverse lookup will need to be a list of items).  While it will be programmatically "expensive" (more in memory than in time, but still some of both) to create this second dictionary, once you do you would be able to efficiently query based on values rather than keys.

Comment: You can also implement MaxBy yourself.  It's just a few lines of code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8759648/385844

Comment: @phoog I'm assuming that the OP would be able to copy/paste the [linked] code for just maxBy and use that, rather than the whole project (unless he's interested in it).  Indeed, it isn't all that much code.  In fact, the entirety of Linq to objects isn't all that much code, considering everything it does and how often it's used.  Thank you iterator blocks.

Answer (score 0):

To get all keys that hold a maximum of the value you are
interested in, some dataprocessing has to be done.
Actually this is quite comfortable in C#.

It can be accomplished by doing some combination of Linq

```
// first of all, group your dictionary by the value you want to have
var groups = dict.GroupBy(d => d.Value);

// then, order those groups by the value
var orderedGroups = groups.OrderBy(g => g.Key);

// after that, you have all the KeyValuePairs that hold the MaxValue here:
var maxKeys = orderedGroups.Last().ToList();
```

Have fun with it!

Comment: +1 for noting that there could be more than one key associated with the max value.